# Xamarin VS 2017 cannot render iOS storyboard document

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I started a new Xamarin cross platform project in VS 2017 on a windows. The android portion works fine, but when I try to open the iOS Main.Storyboard file, I get an error. I am connected to a mac which has xcode 8.3.

Xamarin.iOS version on windows VS - 10.4.0.123

Xamarin iOS version on VS community 2017 on mac - 10.12.0.18

I cannot find any answers other than downgrading xcode. I think the issue probably has to do with the Xamarion.iOS versions not matching, but I can't figure out how to resolve that. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Full error log:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The returned remote SDK entries are invalid
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IosSdkTarget.InitializeLocalFileStore()
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IosSdkTarget..ctor(Version xcodeVersion, DataPackEntry[] datapack, String storeDirectory)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<SetupSession>d__257.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<>c__DisplayClass256_0`1.<EnsureSession>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXmlWithPartialReloadRetry>d__175.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXmlWithPartialReloadRetry>d__175.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXml>d__174.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<RenderXml>d__174.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<ReloadItemsAsync>d__170.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Tasks.<Cancellable>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<ReloadItems>d__169.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: The returned remote SDK entries are invalid
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IosSdkTarget.InitializeLocalFileStore()
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IosSdkTarget..ctor(Version xcodeVersion, DataPackEntry[] datapack, String storeDirectory)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<SetupSession>d__257.MoveNext()<---


Contents of C:\Users\Jdoyle\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Logs\15.0\iOSDesigner-11168.2017-08-21__16-14-59.log:
MDAddinsHash: 1363a8d943bab7700c93a97474060b6734aa7f94

[2017-08-21 16:17:10.2] INFO: Starting full reload...
[2017-08-21 16:17:10.8] INFO: Reloading: Serialization took 0ms
[2017-08-21 16:17:30.4] INFO: Reloading: Deserialization took 13ms
[2017-08-21 16:17:30.4] INFO: Reloading: Server rendering completed in 19520ms with 52744 bytes
[2017-08-21 16:17:30.4] ERROR: EnsureSession (counter 1): System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The returned remote SDK entries are invalid
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IosSdkTarget.InitializeLocalFileStore()
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IosSdkTarget..ctor(Version xcodeVersion, DataPackEntry[] datapack, String storeDirectory)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<SetupSession>d__257.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: The returned remote SDK entries are invalid
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IosSdkTarget.InitializeLocalFileStore()
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IosSdkTarget..ctor(Version xcodeVersion, DataPackEntry[] datapack, String storeDirectory)
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<SetupSession>d__257.MoveNext()<---
```

**Edit Solution**

For anyone having this same issue, installing the Xamarin updates extension for VS & updating the Xamarin Apple SDK fixed this issue for me. Follow the steps [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/extension-gallery/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version fixes it.

In addition when using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows I had the same issue.
Upgrading Xamarin (stable channel on mac & windows) and updating Visual Studio 2017 to the latest version (15.0.26228.12) fixed it for me.

**see:** [https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-xcode-8-3-support-for-vs-2017/][1]

Comment: I don't see a way to upgrade xamarin for VS 2017 though. The docs just tell you to update Visual Studio (which I did).https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/

Answer (score 0):

My best advice to this issue is to `NEVER` use the `IOS designer`. It's rubbish. Always use Xcode Interface Builder. The main reason is, you're guaranteed the storyboard will be valid with IOS. I once created an empty storyboard in IOS Designer and compared the XML it generated to an empty storyboard created in Xcode. It was totally different. The designer version was missing a hell of a lot of information. Since then I have never trusted the IOS designer. Not only that, but constraints are pain in the ass to use on the IOS designer, whereby, they're a lot easier in Xcode. I've also have storyboards render totally wrong in the IOS designer if the layout is particularly complex.